# Shared memory Reader (read only) hangs when Writer terminates

Tags: c, memory, shared, writer

In linux, C, using shared memory, I have a single Writer process and many Readers.

When the Writer terminates, any running Readers hang. The Writer does do shm_unlink when it terminates.

I thought, may be wrongly, that the kernel knows about the Readers and that they can continue to read. Of course the data will not change, so the Readers can know when to end gracefully.

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a flag in a header you create in the shared memory to indicate EOF.  You could have a timestamp you update periodically to detect writer unclean termination/

You can also use shmctl to find out the number of attached people, which might help you figure out if the writer has gone away.

You can also try to re-attach/fstat to validate that the segment has not been deleted.

If these answers do not satisfy, please let us know whether it is POSIX or System V shared memory.

Comment: The writer is setting flags now in the shared memory for the readers. This works But, the flags are no good, ie, when the reader hangs.

Comment: @user768184: What system call is the reader hanging on?  Typically it would be polling a write hand or something like that for updates.  While it is polling the write hand you can poll the EOF flag or timestamp field.

Comment: I have not run it in gdb, so not sure of exact call. Yes, the readers are on regular timed reads, usually 25 milliseconds. The flags are no good after the reader gets hung. The system is POSIX, so I guess shm_<>, mmap and munmap are my tools. I think the Reader must somehow know the Writer did a shm_unlink before getting hung trying to read.

Answer (score 0):

In linux, the kernel doesn't know about your readers or writers (or, well, it doesn't know which is which). And `shm_unlink` just removes the name; it doesn't delete the shmem segment until all users have unmapped and closed it or terminated. If you're having these readers/writers communicate and block through  [pshared](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread_mutexattr_getpshared.html) mutexes/semaphores, then when the writer dies you could indeed end up with hanging readers. It's best to have the writer leave a message in the queue to tell the readers that it's terminating.